# Mirror X axis-pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I have to plot a hysteresis data. Instead of putting it in a single plot. I would like to put it in 2 plots but I want X-axis of second plot to be a mirror image first plot's x axis. How can I do this in pgfplot?

See figure for clarification
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example use `x post scale=-1` for the second axis. To remove any gap between them, set the location of the second axis to the `south east` anchor of the first one, and set its anchor to `south west`. `x axis line style={-}` added *after* `axis lines`/`axis x line` will remove the arrow head.

To place an x-label in the middle, easiest is to add a `\node` after the `axis` environments, placed below the `south east` corner of the first axis.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every outer x axis line/.style={-}}
\begin{axis}[
  name=ax1,
  axis lines=left,
  x axis line style={-}]
\addplot{x};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis y line=right,
  x axis line style={-},
  x post scale=-1,
  at={(ax1.south east)},
  anchor=south west]
\addplot{x};
\end{axis}

\node [below=1cm] at (ax1.south east) {Common xlabel};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.That worked like charm . But I'd like to have a common x-label. Also I want to reduce the gap between the 2 graphs so that the X-axis looks like a single line. How can I do that?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar See edited answer.